# Custom Deserialization using Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class

```
public class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ShippingMethod { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to deserialize a JSON data below into the above class/object

```
string json = @"{
  'Id': 1,
  'ShippingMethod': {
     'Code': 'external_DHLExpressWorldwide',
     'Description': 'DHL ILS Express Worldwide'
  }
}";
```

My idea is that `ShippingMethod` in JSON is a object, but I just want to get to `ShippingMethod.Code` (in JSON) that will pass into `ShippingMethod` as `string` in `Order` class during deserialization.

how can I accomplish that goal using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

I believe I can accomlish it using [CustomJsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). But I get confused. The example in the docs just for `WriteJson`, but not `ReadJson`.

Comment: So `Code` and `Description` are inside `ShippingMethod`? How are serialized?

Comment: You just need to have "Id" and "Code" at the same level?

Comment: Yeah, that is my problem and what I want to accomplish

Comment: `ShippingMethod` is object in the json and string in C# class. How you can map this. You have to change the code as below.

Comment: @Aruna See my way to map it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net/40439958#40439958

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I just resolve my problem using [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) as I mentioned above in my question. Below my complete code:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ShippingMethodConverter))]
    public string ShippingMethod { get; set; }
}

public class ShippingMethodConverter : JsonConverter
{

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented yet");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        } 
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            if (obj["Code"] != null) 
                return obj["Code"].ToString();
            else 
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
 dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
 var order = new Order
 {
     Id = o.Id,
     ShippingMethod = o.ShippingMethod.Code
 };
```

Deserialize the object as dynamic and then fill the `Order` object by accessing to the dynamic object properties

Comment: +1 for this one. I think this is the best clean way without attribute pollution and new class creation :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it not suitable if there are lot another properties

Comment: You haven't say that there are more properties to manage. To solve this you could add an Extension method that map once and then you can use it wherever you want. But also you solution seems ok, just to much line of code fortwo properties (in my opinion)

Comment: Yes, there look lot of code, but in real word it will keep your model clean.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `JsonProperty` and `JsonIgnore` attributes to direct the deserialization process... So your model can be:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string ShippingMethod
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)TempShippingMethod?["Code"];
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("ShippingMethod")]
    private JObject TempShippingMethod { set; get; }
}
```

---

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(json);
```

Comment: Yeah, that just a tiny hack. I don't like this way, but I upvote :) as my respect to your answer

Comment: @Habibillah I didn't like your answer too, too cumbersome for a simple thing, But as my respect to your opinion, I posted a simplified version of my answer..

Comment: No worries :). The question is simple think, but my real word, with lot of property and bad json schema, it really worth. Example. saving an order, you must pass string, but for getting order detail, you got an object. And many more

Comment: I'd disagree this is a hack. JsonIgnore is designed for this kind of purpose - it means you don't have to re-write the serialization. Presumably, we're missing some context as to why this is not suitable for the OP.

Comment: When using `[JsonProperty("...")]` I'm getting the compiler error `CS0616: 'JsonProperty' is not an attribute class`. I need to use `[JsonPropertyName("...")]` instead. I'm on .Net 7.0

Comment: When serializing this object back, be aware that the original properties will show up.