# How to invoke/model binding validation upon record property assignment in F#

Tags: asp.net, validation, f#

Please let me know a suitable way to invoke the validation attribute at the time of property assignment of a record type.
I have created a custom validation attribute as follows.

```
namespace FloAppCore

module CatalogueAttributes =   
   open System
   open Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
   open Newtonsoft.Json
   open System.Runtime.Serialization
   open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
   open System.Text.RegularExpressions

[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)>]
type IsNameValidAttribute() =
    inherit ValidationAttribute()
    override this.IsValid(value: obj) =
        let mutable result = true
        if(not(isNull(value)) && (value.ToString() <> "")) then
            result <- true

        let fnSpecialCharacter value =
            let pattern = Regex("[@#$%^&*()_+!~:;./?><]$")
            let matches = pattern.Match value
            not(matches.Success)

        if result then
            result <- (fnSpecialCharacter (value.ToString()))

        result

    override this.FormatErrorMessage(name:string) = 
        String.Format(this.ErrorMessageString,name)
```

And I have assigned the attribute to a record type like this.

```
   type Item = {
    mutable Id:string
    [<IsNameValid(ErrorMessage = "{0} value is not valid.")>]
    Brand:string
    ProductName:string
    Description:string
    ItemSizeId:string
    ColourItemId:string
    SpecialCharacteristics:string
   }
```

Unlike ASP.NET MVC I am using Suave with asp.net core and serializing/deserializing json object using Newtonsoft JsonConvert. Like ASP.NET MVC core how can I invoke model binding upon the F# record type in Suave so that the validation attribute gets invoked and restricts the property assignment based upon the validation.

Comment: You're asking how to do this when deserializing json into a record?

Comment: Yes but JSON.NET doesn't serialize using custom attributes. Though Required property is there in JsonProperty attribute but I want to use more customized attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Deserialization using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net)