# Trying to create a custom Json Deserializer for Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am using Azure Location Service to retrieve certain locations. The Json I am returned is an array of objects that are populated like this (data omitted for privacy):

```
{
    "Id": "",
    "Name": "",
    "Address": "",
    "PostCode": "",
    "Location": {
      "Latitude": 123
      "Longitude": -123,
      "IsEmpty": false,
      "Z": null,
      "M": null,
      "CoordinateSystem": {
        "EpsgId": 123,
        "Id": "123",
        "Name": "ABC"
      }
    }
  },
```

I am trying to deserialize into a `LookUpModel` object which has a Microsoft.Spatial.Geography point for its Location:
`public GeographyPoint Location { get; set; }`

When I use the default newtonsoft json deserializer, I receive the following error: "Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].Location.Latitude', line 11, position 17."

Therefore I'm trying to create a custom Json Deserializer which will create a `GeographyPoint` (using `GeographyPoint.Create(Longitude = x, Latitude = y)` whenever the location node is hit. So far I have:

```
public class GeographyPointJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        private readonly Type[] _types;
        public GeographyPointJsonConverter(params Type[] types)
        {
            _types = types;
        }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
            if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                JObject o = (JObject)t;
                IList<string> propertyNames = o.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
                o.AddFirst(new JProperty("Keys", new JArray(propertyNames)));
                o.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
        }
        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return _types.Any(t => t == typeof(GeographyPoint));
        }
    }
```

being called with:  `var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LookUpModel[]>(json, new GeographyPointJsonConverter(typeof(LookUpModel[])));`

However I cannot work out how I can successfully deserialize the Location information into a `GeographyPoint`? Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here please?

Answer (score 2):

You class will be look like this

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PostCode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Location")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public partial class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("Latitude")]
    public long Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Longitude")]
    public long Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsEmpty")]
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Z")]
    public object Z { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("M")]
    public object M { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CoordinateSystem")]
    public CoordinateSystem CoordinateSystem { get; set; }
}

public partial class CoordinateSystem
{
    [JsonProperty("EpsgId")]
    public long EpsgId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your Json,  comma (,) is missing after

```
"Latitude": 123
```

Deserialize you json into object as

```
MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you @BhaveshPatel , although I don't want to deserialize it that way, I want to create a Microsoft.Spatial.Geography Type from the json when deserializing it via the custom converter

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439958/10945191
I hope it will help.

Comment: There is now a MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter in nuget Microsoft.Azure.Core.Spatial ... also similar nuget if you use NewtonSoft