# Using a Custom Json Deserializer to create a new object

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have the following class. I am trying to deserialize Json into an array of these `LookUpData` objects:

```
 [DataContract]
    public class LookUpData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public GeographyPoint Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Json data looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": "123",
    "Location": {
      "Latitude": 1,
      "Longitude": -1,
      }
    }
  },
```

I want to create a custom Json Deserializer so that when reading the Json and hits 'Location', it will create a new GeographyPoint type at that moment, from the Latitude and Longitude values.

I have looked at Newtonsoft's documentation at the Custom Json Serializer as well as helpful answers on Stack Overflow such as this one [Custom Deserialization using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net/40439958#40439958) already, but I can't find an example of how to actually **create** a new type when deserializing. For example the error I receive at the moment using the standard deserializer is 'Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated".

I'd be grateful if anyone could please point me in the right direction here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It always creates a "new" instance for everything when deserializing.

Comment: What is wrong with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LookUpData>>(jsonString)` ?

Comment: I have updated my question @rory.ap with more explanation - apologies this wasn't clear. I need to create a new 'type' (GeographyPoint') which is created from the longitude and latitude values. At the moment using the standard deserializer, I receve the error : 'Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated".

Comment: create own `MyGeographyPoint` class  with `Latitude` and `Longitude` props ... make private field of this type in you class and let default deserialize dezerialize to it ...then add getter which at the first time use  `GeographyPoint.Create` and data from `MyGeographyPoint` to create real `GeographyPoint` and return it (similiar to L.B answer in your link)

Comment: Do you need to **serialize** as well as deserialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for the [`GeographyPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spatial.geographypoint?view=odata-spatial-7.0) type as shown below.  This implementation uses a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) as a means to easily read from (and write to) the JSON.  The key to creating the `GeographyPoint` instance is using the static [`Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spatial.geographypoint.create?view=odata-spatial-7.0#Microsoft_Spatial_GeographyPoint_Create_System_Double_System_Double_) method provided by that type.

```
class GeographyPointConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(GeographyPoint).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken obj = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (obj.Type == JTokenType.Null) return null;
        double latitude = (double)obj["Latitude"];
        double longitude = (double)obj["Longitude"];
        return GeographyPoint.Create(latitude, longitude);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        GeographyPoint point = (GeographyPoint)value;
        JObject obj = new JObject(
            new JProperty("Latitude", new JValue(point.Latitude)),
            new JProperty("Longitude", new JValue(point.Longitude))
        );
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

To use the converter, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `Location` property in your `LookUpData` class:

```
public class LookUpData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(GeographyPointConverter))]
    public GeographyPoint Location { get; set; }
}
```

Note: you don't actually need the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes when using Json.Net, unless you need opt-in semantics — meaning you need to specifically identify which classes and members are included in serialization and deserialization.  If these attributes are omitted, then all classes and members are included by default, which seems to be your intent here.

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNo1vP

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers - really helpful! Just wondering what is the correct way to handle when 'Location' is null and it can't deserialize?

Comment: If the location could possibly be null, then you need to check for that in `ReadJson` and either return null or optionally create a default GeographyPoint.  I've updated my answer with this check.  Note that I had to switch to using `JToken.Load` instead of `JObject.Load`.

Comment: Thank you very much @BrianRogers. I am getting this error: " 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: EndObject. Path '[0].Location', line 21, position 5.'" I am guessing this is because my custom deserializer is trying to deserialize null objects?

Comment: Did you change `JObject.Load` to be `JToken.Load` as shown?  I also updated the fiddle to show working code there as well.