# C# How to convert Unicode char to string value

Tags: c#, json, unicode, formatting

I have a JSON which have a Unicode value in one of his fields, like this: `"OpenCloseSettlFlag": "\u0000"`

I need to format this Unicode value every time I get a new JSON that have different values.

Already tried to use Normalize() methods but nothing works, also tried [Regex.Unescape()][1], which works but converts the entirely JSON instead convert only the unicode field.

Comment: If you're using a decent JSON parser (JSON.NET, System.Text.Json, to name just two), it will read and interpret that escape sequence correctly and give you a string with that character; in that case, it's just a matter of understanding what you get. If you're not, we have no idea what you're doing or how to help. Please [edit] your question to include your code and a full (syntactically complete) sample input.

Comment: That string is already escaped, that's not a real unicode char but it's representation in ASCII. You should check how to create a custom deserializer (if you're using newtonsoft.json this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net)