# How to delete a property in a JArray?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JArray as below, the file property contained a base64 string so it's a big size, how to delete it?

```
{ 
  "files": [
    {
      "filename": "892a3a3bb7814d67995d4059b278c581.png",
      "real_filename": "Logo - Trimmed.png",
      "filesize": 42198,
      "filetype": "image/png",
      "file": "xxxx"
    },
    {
      "filename": "22a3a3bb7814d67995d4059b278c581.png",
      "real_filename": "Logo - Trimmed2.png",
      "filesize": 42198,
      "filetype": "image/png",
      "file": "xxxx"
    }
  ] 
}
```

I have tried below, but it threw me an exception:

> Cannot add or remove items from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

```cs
for (int _i = 0; _i < _ja_files.Count; _i++) 
{
     _ja_files[_i]["file"].Remove();
}
```

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net) can answer yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Iterate the `JObject` in `JArray` and with [`JObject.Remove()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/m_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject_remove.htm) to remove the property.

```cs
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
        
foreach (JObject obj in jObj["files"] as JArray)
{
    obj.Remove("file");
}
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/niUDGf)

---

**Solution 2**

Another approach filters the `JProperty` with `name: "file"` and remove it.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

(jObj["files"] as JArray).Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "file")       
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qr1FLz)