# A list of a lists of deserialized json

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been stuck on a bug for quite some time any help would be appreciated. I have a JSON file, and I need to get nested items from the JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "name": "River",
    "description": "Items By River",
    
     "Items": 
    [
      {
        "element": "Water",
        "color": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "element": "earth",
        "color": "Brown"
      },
      {
        "element": "fire",
        "color": "Orange"
      },
      {
        "element": "air",
        "color": "White"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I parse the JSON Data with Two classes

```
public class Items
{
      public string element
      public string color      
}

public ItemList
{
    public List<Items> items;
}


//Declare 
public ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
```

my Parse function

```
itemList = JsonUtility.FromJson<ItemList>(json);
```

Now, when I do this Unity gives me a list of items. and when I access the items by calling `itemList.items[0]` it returns an object

When I do `itemList.items[0].element`, it gives me the first item in the list.

What I want is a List of the Item List, so when I call ItemList.items[0]

It gives me the full list of items, not just the first one.

```
 {
    "element": "Water",
    "color": "Blue"
  },
  {
    "element": "earth",
    "color": "Brown"
  },
  {
    "element": "fire",
    "color": "Orange"
  },
  {
    "element": "air",
    "color": "White"
  }
```

Comment: You need to have json in the desired structure in first place

Comment: I think you are confusing Json Arrays and Json Objects. From what I can see you are loading an array of objects. and C# gives you exactly that. See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Items[0] can’t give you a whole list. That’s now how lists work. If it’s returning the first element then it’s working.

Comment: @bugfinder I understand that it is working but I want to know the way of how to return the whole list that’s what I am not understanding

Comment: Well itemList is the whole list. And will give you the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json are not matching structure you looking for. But you can use custom serializer/deserializer and define target object structure...

See Microsoft example below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Also check following question for example  [Custom Deserialization using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net)