# Deserialise JSON file without property identifiers

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I would like to deserialise a JSON file in C# where there are no property identifiers. A section of the file is shown below:

```json
{
  "images": [
    {
      "RCNX0001.JPG": [
        [0.9034, 0.4013, 0.94784, 0.41594, 0.0101, 1], 
        [0.9062, 0.5073, 0.9770300000000001, 0.53855, 0.0105, 1], 
        [0.7784, 0.1293, 0.85478, 0.16396, 0.0323, 1]
      ]
    },
    {
      "RCNX0002.JPG": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Added after very useful comment from dbc

The solution proposed by dbc is very good, but requires a higher version of C# than is available in my .NET Framework project. My code based on his response is below. The input file is slightly different:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

double[] detectionParams = new double [6];
string sImageName = "";
var reader = new StreamReader(sFile);
var model = (Model)JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize(reader, typeof(Model));

for (int iImage = 0; iImage < model.images.Count; iImage++)
{
    double max_detection_conf = 0.0;
    sImageName = model.images[iImage].ToList()[0].Key;
    for (int iDetection = 0; iDetection < model.images[iImage].ToList()[0].Value.Count; iDetection++)
    {
        for (int iParam = 0; iParam <= 5; iParam++)
        {
            detectionParams[iParam] = model.images[iImage].ToList()[0].Value[iDetection][iParam];
            if (detectionParams[4] > max_detection_conf && detectionParams[5] == 1) max_detection_conf = detectionParams[4];
        }
    }   
}

public class Model
{
    public string section { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<List<double>>>> images { get; set; } = new List<Dictionary<string, List<List<double>>>>();
}

Input File

{"images": [
{"RCNX0001.JPG": [[0.9034, 0.4013, 0.94784, 0.41594, 0.0101, 1], [0.9062, 0.5073, 0.9770300000000001, 0.53855, 0.0105, 1], [0.7784, 0.1293, 0.85478, 0.16396, 0.0323, 1]]}
,{"RCNX0002.JPG": []}
]}
```

Comment: What kind of object do you want to deserialise it to?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issues are you having?

Comment: *"where there are no property identifiers"* - you have to clarify which part is the property identifier. though you should try [custom deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439290/custom-deserialization-using-json-net). we can't tell you much without expected output and the version of your .net.

Comment: I want to have access to all the elements of the file

Comment: I've tried`string sText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sFile);
                dynamic jsonDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sText);
                var jarrayString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDict["images"]);
                var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, InternalDetectionsList>>(jarrayString);`.  with `public class InternalDetectionsList
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DetectionResults")]
        public IList<IList<double>> InternalDetections { get; set; }
    }` but get error

Comment: Why do you have `InternalDetectionsList`? That's an object, not an array. Your C# model has to accurately reflect your JSON. Your JSON dictionary value should be an array of arrays of double.

Comment: Please post your code by updating the question. Don't post it in the comment as it is difficult to be read.

Comment: @SimonKravis - I updated my answer to not use the most recent C# language features.  Note that `model.images[iImage].ToList()[0]` is not very efficient because it copies the dictionary to a list of key/value pairs, then selects the first one.  `FirstOrDefault()` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON corresponds to the following model:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<List<double>>>> images { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

It can be deserialized successfully by either System.Text.Json:

```
using var stream = File.OpenRead(sFile);
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(stream)!;
```

Or Json.NET:

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(sFile);
var model = (Model)JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize(reader, typeof(Model))!;
```

Then to loop through all the images and get the corresponding list of list of doubles, you could do e.g.:

```
foreach (var (name, values) in model.images.SelectMany(d => d))
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"For image {name}, values = {JsonSerializer.Serialize(values)}.");
}
```

Or if you are working

Which outputs

```
For image RCNX0001.JPG, values = [[0.9034,0.4013,0.94784,0.41594,0.0101,1],[0.9062,0.5073,0.9770300000000001,0.53855,0.0105,1],[0.7784,0.1293,0.85478,0.16396,0.0323,1]].
For image RCNX0002.JPG, values = [].
```

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iHaF0l) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3nX75).

**Update**

If you are working on an earlier version of .NET that does not support e.g. [deconstructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.deconstruct) or the [using declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration), you can do:

```
public class Model
{
    public Model() { this.images =  new List<Dictionary<string, List<List<double>>>>(); }
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<List<double>>>> images { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
Model model;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sFile))
    model = (Model)JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize(reader, typeof(Model));

foreach (var pair in model.images.SelectMany(d => d))
{
    var name = pair.Key; // string
    var values = pair.Value; // List<List<double>>
    Console.WriteLine("For image {0}, values = {1}.",
                      name, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values));
}
```

Or if you only want the first image in each dictionary in the list for some reason, do:

```
foreach (var pair in model.images.Where(d => d.Count > 0).Select(d => d.FirstOrDefault()))
{
    var name = pair.Key; // string
    var values = pair.Value; // List<List<double>>
    Console.WriteLine("For image {0}, values = {1}.",
                      name, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values));
}
```

Notes:

- The above syntax works as far back as .NET Framework 4.7.  LINQ's `SelectMany()` was introduced in [.NET 3.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-3.5) so it is almost certain you framework includes it.
- `d.FirstOrDefault()` will be more efficient than `model.images[iImage].ToList()[0]`.  The latter copies the entire dictionary to a list or key/value pairs, then takes the first entry. [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) merely takes the first entry from an enumerable without enumerating the entire thing.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mxjpe2).